# Filtering GET results in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello supposing i have a **users** table with the following columns; **first_name**, **last_name**, **email**, **role**, **created_at**.

Now my admin wants to search for all users **with a specific first_name.**
Obviously the code would be lyk this:

```
$users = User::select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'role', 'created_at')->where('first_name', 'smith')->get();
```

Now after that i would like to search for all users  who **have a specific last_name** within the previous results.

Then I would like to search all users who **have a specific role** within the previously returned results.

Then I would like to search for all users who were **created on a specific date or within a specific period** using the previously returned results.

The above is just an example of what i would like to do.
I would like to do that by fetching data from my database only once (if possible).

Comment: Use the Collection methods once you have the first collection from your database.

Comment: Have you looked into dropping all users into something like DataTables and letting the searches happen all on the client side?

Comment: Is this for some kind of filters? For example, do the query by Name, OR Last Name, or Name AND Last name?

Comment: Yes it is for "some kind of filters" however the results need to be filtered in a specific order and each filter results is based on the previous filter's results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Collection methods once you have the first collection from your database.

```
$users = User::where('first_name', 'smith')->get();
// You don't have to use select unless you don't want to get all columns from your table. 

$specific_last_name = $users ->where('last_name', 'john');
```

Check out the collection methods for me: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#available-methods

Comment: Thanks will check it out. :)

Comment: The issue i am having is I seem unable to compare dates inside the collection, with a table i would have just used DB:Raw

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do your query by First Name or by Last Name, you could just do a single query, for example:

```
$request = Request::all();

// Start the query
$query = User::query();

// Query by First Name
if($request->has('first_name')) {
  $query->where('first_name', 'John');
}

// Query by Last Name
if($request->has('last_name')) {
  $query->where('last_name', 'Doe');
}

// Get All the results
$users = $query->get();
```

With this you may give only the first name, only the last name or both. Then you may add additional queries you want to perform.